# How do I convert int* to int (*p)(void)?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
int (*p)(void);
int *i;
...
p = (int *(void))i;
```

But it's causing syntax error:

```
error: cast specifies function type
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Just to learn c's hidden syntax.

Comment: What do you mean 'hidden syntax'?

Comment: Those I'm not very familiar with:)

Comment: Well, trust us (the answerers) unless you have a very good reason for doing this, don't try. It's just kind of meaningless. There are plenty of real interesting corners and pitfalls in C that you can spend your time learning about!

Comment: Actually I've never met any platforms that have different sized pointers.

Comment: Often it comes down to principle. Of course, everybody's `long` is the same size as `long long`, everyone's `NULL` is zero etc. That doesn't mean you don't have to do things by the book.

Comment: @Je Rog: I just worked on a platform (embedded Freescale) where data pointers and function pointers had different sizes.  I finally experienced a real-world example of how trying to cast a `void *` to a function pointer is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should respect error in this case. You must not convert a pointer to function to an int pointer or other way around. That might result in undefined behavior.

If you insist then, syntax should be:

```
p = (int (*)(void))i;
```

Comment: So the root cause is `(*)` missing... what's the difference b/w `(int (*)(void))` and `(int *(void))`? I was regarding them as the same thing...

Comment: @Je Rog: `int *(void)` is type of function (not pointer, the function itself) taking no arguments and returning `int *`. You can have expressions of that type (the function name alone or dereference of function pointer have it), but not variables or parameters of that type and so you also can't cast to that type.

Answer (score 3):

i is a pointer to an integer, and p is a function pointer returning and int and taking no arguments. They are not compatible/castable in any way, shape or form.

Answer (score 2):

What the compiler says. `int (*p)(void)` is a function pointer declaration (pointer to a function which returns an int). `int *i;` is a scalar pointer declaration (pointer to an int). You can't cast one into the other.

Comment: What exactly does `(int *(void))` mean(I now understand it doesn't mean a function pointer,but what it means)?

Comment: Nope. Can't make sense of that, sorry. Where did you get it from?

Comment: Well I don't think it means anything.

Comment: The language doesn't define the behavior of converting between pointer-to-object and pointer-to-function types, but it doesn't actually forbid it.  If you get the syntax right, you *can* cast an int* to a function pointer, or vice versa.  There's just no guarantee that the result will be meaningful -- or, for that matter, that your program won't blow up, or even fail to compile.

Comment: Case in (kind of vague) point. Some of the routines in the Apple Core Foundation have functions with whatever-you-want as arguments. See this question regarding kauth, where there are just-in-case-whatever-you-want arguments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067941/why-do-polymorphic-calls-such-as-listener-in-kauth-have-anonymous-arguments-rat

Answer (score 2):

Write

```
p = (int (*)(void))i;
```

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(){
    printf("test\n");
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int (*p)(void);
    int *i;

    i = (int*)f;

    p = (int (*)(void))i;

    printf("i=%p\n", i);
    printf("p=%p\n", p);

    ((int (*)(void))i)(); //here, it will call f()

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's the difference b/w `(int (*)(void))` and `(int *(void))`?

Comment: @Je Rog: `(int (*)(void))` is the type that **a pointer to a function, and the function returns an int and has no arguments**. `(int *(void))` is not a valid type. Aside: `int *f(void)` means a function `f` that returns an `int*` and has no arguments.

Comment: @Je Rog: using the `typedef` will make it more clear to understand :p

Answer (score 1):

If you must do it ( and I am in no way saying that you should) then:

```
typedef int (*fp)(void);
int *i;
fp p;
...
p = (fp)((void*)i);
```

Answer (score 0):

`*i` points to a simple integer, while `*p` is a pointer to a function with no arguments *returning* an integer. Thus, these two have completely different types, and because you said `p` shall point to a function returning an int, you can not tell it to point to an int.

However, you can try to wrap both in a union like the following:

```
union u {
  int *i;
  int (*p)(void);
};

int f(void){
  return 5;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  union u myU;
  int a=6;
  myU.i=&a;
  myU.p=&f;
  return 0;
}
```

Note that after assigning `&f`, you can simply call `myU.p()`. But if you leave out the assignment of `&f` and call `myU.p()` afterwards, it results in undefined behaviour (i.e. program crashes).

Answer (score 0):

You don't. That is, unless you know better than the compiler that the pointer stored in your `int *` came from an `int (*p)(void)` in the first place. As others have said, that second type is a pointer to a function that takes no parameters and returns an int. The first type is a simple pointer to an integer (or more than one integer if treated as an array).